# Idle animation not triggering on keyup

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a player and I want to move the player from left to right. I can move the player by the keyboard events. But the problem is that when I release the key the player animation should be idle. It's not working. Why?

```
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward*Time.deltaTime);
        animation.Play("Walk_with_Bin_001");
        animation["Walk_with_Bin_001"].wrapMode = WrapMode.Loop;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        animation.Stop("Walk_with_Bin_001");
        animation.Play("Idle");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Animation or Animator? Does it stop the Bin animation?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may have mixed up your keycodes for your if statement conditions. In the first block, you're checking for the keydown of `KeyCode.RightArrow` - but in your second block, you're checking for the keyup of `KeyCode.UpArrow`.

This means that even if you release the right arrow key, "Walk_with_Bin_001" will continue playing in a loop until you press up arrow key. Change the second condition to also use `KeyCode.RightArrow`, and your code should do what you expect it to, like so:

```
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.RightArrow))
{
    animation.Stop("Walk_with_Bin_001");
    animation.Play("Idle");
}
```